# Chef Automation: Global Counter / Variable?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have two **chef cookbooks** (and potentially more) that needs a **unique id** (integer) when executed, in best case they are **sequential**.

Are there any possibilities to have a central storage of variables, a global variable which is not a constant? That can be incremented each time my default recipe of a cookbook is executed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to do this with purely Chef. The usual approaches are either to allocate the ID numbers by hand up front in node attributes or to use a hash of the node name or some other stable value. `node.name.hash % 1000` would give you something between 0 and 1000 that is *roughly* evenly distributed. Unfortunately the name hashing isn't designed with collision resistance in mind so on smaller ranges (like 0-256) it can have an unfortunate streak.

If you really want to do this "properly" look at tools like Consul and ZooKeeper which can issue sequential numbers safely in a distributed situation.

Comment: Fortunate coincidence that I actually use ZooKeeper. So my exact setup is the following: I have a cookbook to create a server instance of ZooKeeper + Apache Kafka, and a cookbook for just a Kafka server instance that connects to the previous ZooKeeper instance. And the problem is actually that I have to set the broker id (unique integer) of every additional Kafka broker / server, dynamically. Do you have an idea how to use ZooKeeper for this? Can I request a new number?

Comment: If you search around for "zookeeper counter" you can find the official ZK recipes. I know the Python library (kazoo) has an impl of them, but I don't think the Ruby client(s) do. There is the `zookeeper` gem which is relatively low-level and then the `ZK` gem that builds on top of that.